# VBA Excel: error 1004 when using Range.Find method

Tags: excel, range, vba

I am learning about the Range.Find method. I have a column of letters (a to t) in column A of Excel, from row 1 to row 20.

This code:

```
Public Sub MyFind3()

'Accepts an input for a fluid length search field (column A)
Dim WhatToFind As String
Dim DataRange As Range

Set DataRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
WhatToFind = InputBox("Enter text to search for:", "Find Text")
Range(DataRange).Find(WhatToFind).Select

End Sub
```

...works up to the last line when I get this error:
"Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined Error".
It does not find the Find match.
Can anyone point out my error please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Find()` returns a range that you'll usually want to assign to a range variable. I would rework your code slightly like this:

```
Public Sub MyFind3()

'Accepts an input for a fluid length search field (column A)
Dim WhatToFind As String
Dim DataRange As Range

WhatToFind = InputBox("Enter text to search for:", "Find Text")
Set DataRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find(What:=WhatToFind)
if not DataRange is Nothing then
  DataRange.select
else
  msgbox (WhatToFind & " wasn't found")
end if

End Sub
```

That gives you the advantage of being able to handle the 'not found' condition, and you have a range var you can now do something else with.

Also, be aware that when you call `.Find()`, it will execute with whatever the last settings were, so setting more of the parameters, such as `LookIn`, `LookAt`, and `MatchCase` will help ensure that this search works exactly as you intend.

Comment: Thank you FreeMan. For the _no-find_ trap, I was going to use something like:
    If DataRange Is Nothing Then  
    MsgBox (WhatToFind & " not found.")  
    Exit Sub  
    Else  
    DataRange.Select  
    End If  
...but your version looks far neater.
Thank you again. By the way, sorry but I cannot get this into a correctly formatted form.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to:

```
DataRange.Find(WhatToFind).Select
```

`DataRange` is already a `Range` object, so does not need to be listed as `Range(DataRange)`

Comment: I was looking at that for over 15 minutes and I never spotted it. Many thanks! I'm surprised though that it gives an error message - not very forgiving. Thank you again.