# Type Mismatch error when using range.find method

Tags: excel, vba, types, mismatch

Could anyone help me with using the range.find method. The type mismatch error keeps coming up and I'm not sure why.

I've tried setting the range variable to a Range, then using Set to define it and I've also tried without using Set, but then it comes up with another error.

```
Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind").row
```

I expect the above code to give me the row of the WhatToFind, and it is definitely in the worksheet, but still gives the error.

Even if I remove the `.Row` from the end, I get this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application or Object defined error

Comment: Also, when I remove the .row at the end of the Set line, it comes up with error 1004. Any ideas??

Comment: On its own that code (without the `.Row`) shouldn't return an error - if it doesn't find the "WhatToFind" then it will set `r1` as nothing.  If `r1` is nothing then an error will occur when you try and do anything with it.  What is the description for error `1004`?

Comment: The description is  application or object defined error.

Comment: @ClaireGomes I have added that error detail to your post (It is important) - if the error message doesn't exactly match, then please edit the question to include the exact text of the error

Comment: Did you find out why this error happened?

Comment: It seems as though I can only run code once in my Excel, then it gives this error and other errors unnecessarily. After I close and re-open it, it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fully qualifying your range (e.g. `Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind")`)

If you leave it unqualified, it will try to use the `ActiveSheet`.  If you are, for example, looking at a Chartsheet instead of a Worksheet, then this will throw a 1004 error - because the `ActiveSheet`, being a chart, doesn't have any cells, columns, or Ranges to search.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that something is found before you can return anything from it.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim lFoundRow As Long
    Set r1 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind")
    If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "WhatToFind is on row " & r1.Row
        lFoundRow = r1.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

I doubt this is the cause of the error, but `FIND` remembers the settings from the last time it was used (either through code or manually on the worksheet with `Ctrl+F`).

You can set each parameter on the `FIND`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:K")
        Set r1 = .Find( _
            What:="WhatToFind", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            MatchByte:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
            lRow = r1.Row
        Else
            MsgBox "Not found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Strangely it's still giving error 1004 object defined error on line Set r1 = Range...., even if i remove Set and just have r1 = Range....

Answer (score 1):

Your r1 is a range type, but

Set r1 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind").row - is not a Range. It's number.

Use

```
Set r1 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind")
dim r1row
r1row = r1.row
```

Or

```
dim lR as long
lR = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind").Row
```

But remember, that Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind") can be "Nothing"

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of the type mismatch error but now it says error 1004, object defined error. Any ideas? Also I am working in the Worksheet_Change section if that makes a difference.

Comment: `code`    Dim r1 As Long
        r1 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind").row

Comment: I have only Run-time error '91', when Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind") is nothing, u can use **if not (Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind")) is Nothing then** construction. Maybe check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287975/vba-excel-error-1004-when-using-range-find-method)

Answer (score 1):

The `Row` Property is a type long, and it represents the row number, not the row (Range) object itself.

If you want the row object, you probabaly want `EntireRow`.

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 as Long
Set r1 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind").EntireRow
r2 = Range("B:K").Find("WhatToFind").Row
```

And just to clarify, although you might already know this, `set` is only used for reference types.  Since a long is a value type, you do not use the set command.

Answer (score 0):

## Add-in?

**There is no Worksheet**. You are running this code from e.g. an Add-in or you are trying to run this code on an chart sheet. You have to select a Worksheet  in the tab.

Comment: Good idea... could you expand on it a bit though.  I was thinking chart sheet, but doesn't give that error.

Comment: @VBasic2008 [*"The description is application or object defined error" - Claire Gomes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866586/type-mismatch-error-when-using-range-find-method/53867317#comment94581258_53866586) - but running the code from a Chart sheet gives a '1004' with a different description *"Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"*.  Same (generic) number, different error message

Comment: @Chronocidal  I got `Object doesn't support this property or method` (as a chart sheet doesn't have `Range("B:K")`

Comment: Just thought - an Add-In does have sheets, they're just hidden and without qualifying the code will be searching the active sheet on the active book and not the Add-In.  Even when qualifying it just searches the hidden sheet (although it may not find anything as it's hidden - it's not finding data on a hidden column, so I expect the same with a hidden sheet).

Comment: I could have sworn that in the Post or its comments the Method Rang error was mentioned. But I still think that something like this happened. I guess will never find out.