# Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the code that is column letter agnostic. It searches for the column header by name:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim column1, column2 As String
Dim lr, lc As Long
Dim col1, col2 As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lc = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

With ws
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    lr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Range("A1"), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lr = 1
End If
End With

column1 = "Column 1"
column2 = "Column 2"

Set col1 = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=column1, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

MsgBox(col1.Column)

Set col2 = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=column2, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

MsgBox(col2.Column)
With ws.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))
    ' The line below this generates a Run-time error 1004: 
    ' Application-defined or Object-defined error with or without 
    ' the ws.Range(ws.Cells(#, #), ws.Cells(#, #) qualifier.
    .Range(.Cells(2, col1.Column), .Cells(lr, 
    col1.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=IF(LEN(RC[col2.Column])>1,RC[col2.Column]*1,"""")"
End With
```

Column 2 has dates, some with leading zeros, that I want to remove. I plan on placing these dates in Column 1 after applying the above formula. Then:

```
With ws.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))
    .Range(.Cells(2, col1.Column), .Cells(lr, col1.Column)).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(2, col1.Column), .Cells(lr, 
    col1.Column)).PasteSpecial xlValues
    .Range(.Cells(2, col2.Column), .Cells(lr, 
    col2.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[col1.Column]"
End With
```

^ I'm guessing that this will also generate a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Any ideas to correct this will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! Mods - PLEASE note that this question is NOT answered anywhere on StackOverflow. Linked answers have been applied, and they fail to solve this issue.

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate it is a good idea to test that `find` actually found something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287975/vba-excel-error-1004-when-using-range-find-method

Comment: @Warcupine Thanks! Linked is not a duplicate, as the answer it provides, ie qualifying Cells() with ws.Cells(), does not solve my issue. However, I did test .Find code. A MsgBox(col1), which returned column number "1 " as expected. I'm still getting a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Comment: the likely issue is you're applying the `.column` in the same line, if `find` doesn't find anything it is an empty object which has no `.column` property. You'll need to change the variables to Ranges to avoid the type mismatch and use `set`.

Comment: @Warcupine Thanks! Find is working, as the MsgBox proves, so .column does have a property. I edited the code above after changing col1 and col2 Dim As Range and applying Set. I still get a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: @norie - this line of code generates the error: ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, col1.Column), ws.Cells(lr, col1.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = 
"=IF(LEN(RC[col2.Column])>1,RC[col2.Column]*1,"""")"

Comment: You need to replace `col1.column` and `col2.column` with the actual values, Once you've dont that you'll probably need to check you are getting the correct formula.

Comment: @norie Range(Cells(#, #), Cells(#, #)  eliminates the need for actual values. Using actual range values like Range(A1:B10) is not an option as the workbook is extremely dynamic. Column A could be located in column AC next week.

Comment: I meant you need to replace `col1.column` and `col2.column` in the formula.

Comment: @norie Again, not possible. The workbook is too dynamic. MsgBox (col1.Column) and MsgBox (col2.Column) prove that col1.Column and col2.Column are returning numerical values, which is what .Range(.Cells(#, #), .Cells(#, #) is expecting.

Comment: So, you literally want to put this exact formula `"=IF(LEN(RC[col2.Column])>1,RC[col2.Column]*1,"""")"` into the cells? Rather than replacing `col1.Column` and `col2.Column` with their actual values? If you do then Excel will be looking for two named ranges called `col1.Column` and `col2.Column`.

Comment: @norie Yes. If this problem was ever solved on StackOverflow (I don't believe that it has been, despite the linked answers which do not work in my example), I could apply the above formula into col1, then col1.Copy, col1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, and finally transfer those col1 values back to col2.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `col1.Column` and `col2.Column` in the formula with their values? e.g. `"=IF(LEN(RC[" & col2.Column & "])>1,RC[" & col2.Column & "]*1,"""")"`

Comment: @norie Thanks! "=IF(LEN(RC[" & col2.Column & "])>1,RC[" & col2.Column & "]*1,"""")" is the first suggestion that has not resulted in an error. The only issue is that the macro is not multiplying col2 values *1. It's pulling in an unrelated, undefined column, which is odd since you don't appear to be referencing a wild card.

Comment: Are the columns referenced in the formula correct?